# Bi-directional Conversion Between CAN and ARINC825: Software or Hardware Necessities?

Tags: avionics, software

community!

I'm delving into a project that necessitates the conversion of **ARINC825 bus input signals to  CAN outputs**, and vice versa, requiring **CAN inputs to be converted back to ARINC825 outputs** (my software only handles CAN inputs and outputs at the moment). This crossover has led me to ponder whether such conversions can be exclusively handled through software solutions, or if there's a definitive need for hardware integration to bridge these protocols effectively.

Additionally, I'm on the lookout for any existing solutions that cater to this specific requirement. Are there any off-the-shelf, plug-and-play systems designed to facilitate this type of signal conversion with minimal setup?

Your insights or experiences with similar conversions would be immensely valuable to me. If you're aware of any relevant software, hardware, or integrated systems, please share your recommendations.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and knowledge sharing!

Comment: It might be worth clarifying if the proposed solution is just for bench testing/non aviation use, or if it will be going up in an aircraft at some point since that will change the options a bit.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up that distinction @GremlinWranger. To clarify, the solution we're discussing will indeed be used in an aircraft. Looking forward to your insights with this in mind.

Comment: What do you mean with converting ARINC 825 to CAN? My understanding is that CAN is the electrical interface and ARINC 825 is the message format on top of it.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Rainer P. Basically, I have ARINC 825 inputs but my software currently only processes standard CAN messages. I also need to output data as ARINC 825 signals, but my software only outputs standard CAN. I'm unsure about any specific hardware requirements for ARINC 825 on top of the hardware to do this conversion.

Comment: Again, what conversion? What conversion hardware? Your signals are already CAN. The AIRINC 825 standard tells you which packet identifier means airspeed/altitude/etc. Thats all software and one abstraction layer above CAN.